# Difficulty Understanding Conjugate points of a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations

[image]
I was struggling to understand this footnote from the book by Gelfand. I couldnot understand how he takes the solution of the differential equation
[image]
 outside the interval $[a,b]$ and also how will the solution of $(26)$ with initial condition 
$$h(a-\epsilon)=0$$ $$h'(a-\epsilon)=1$$
Cannot vanish on whole interval $[a,b]$

Comment: A conjugate point is a second/the next greater root of $h$?

Answer (score 1):

$P,Q$ are defined outside $[a,b]$ by the implicit assumptions of the cited footmark. Also, if $P$ is non-zero on $[a,b]$, then it is also non-zero on some open neighborhood of that interval. A linear ODE has solutions that can be extended to the full intervals over which the coefficients are continuous and the leading coefficient is non-zero.

This all makes it possible to take the initial condition at $a−ϵ$ for a sufficiently small positive $ϵ$.

For the overall claim, the conjugate point is a continuous function of the initial point. If it is greater than $b$ for initial point $a$, then that same is true for initial points in a neighborhood of $a$, simply by continuity.

Comment: "_the conjugate point is a continuous function of the initial point_", i dont know about this can you shed some light about it.

Comment: This is the meaning of the first sentence: "The solution ... depends continuously on the initial conditions" and by the implicit function theorem, the root depends continuously on the solution, as it has to be a simple one (as all roots of a non-trivial solution of a 2nd order linear DE have to be).